# Android Special characters in the URL name

Tags: android, ioexception

I am getting  java.io.IOException: Illegal character in host name at index 0:
when i try to getconnection to an URL . The URL name has " _ " ( underscore.
Is there a way to handle these special characters.

I saw using java IDN, but its not supported in Android ( right ? )

Comment: Can we have a look at the url?

Answer (score 0):

Use `TextUtils` utilities to encode your url. Use `String htmlEncode (String s)` of this class.

Refer this [document](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextUtils.html#htmlEncode%28java.lang.String%29) for more info.

Comment: OOOPS ITS NOT WORKING, WRONG TESTING ;)

Comment: where is underscore placed? what is the protocol?

Comment: htmlEncode is actually working, it was an error with the domain server.

Comment: @preetha suraj, what are you doing ? this is not a play-ground that you can play comment-comment. Think before putting your question and testing because this wastes many SO user's time. so please

Comment: sorry, my bad. And the comment is CAPS was really an accident. Apologies.

Comment: this is not working for me, TextUtils.htmlEncode returns the same url, which later fails on url.openConnection().connect(); the url is a cover photo in facebook: https://fbcdn_sphotos_a-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-snc7/s720x720/<some numbers here>_n.jpg, should i start a new question or does anybody have a diff solution?

Comment: the link went wrong, here's Mark Zuckerberg's cover photo link, same expection is thrown: https://fbcdn_sphotos_a-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/s720x720/311205_989690200741_1231438675_n.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but this can be helpful to you:

```
    String url = URLEncoder.encode("your url string);
```

Comment: Then sorry, we can't help and throw in air without knowing exact URL.

Comment: i could get it done with htmlEncode , thanks a lot for the pointers